# Wordpress apache benchamrk CPU usage

Tags: load-balancing, wordpress, benchmark, load-testing, stress-testing

I'm on a VPS, 4vCPU 4GB RAM.

During this apache benchmark test:

```
ab -k -n 10000 -c 3 -l URL
```

I get:

```
Server Load 3.393066 (4 CPUs)   
Memory Used 35% (1,358,560 of 3,881,408)    
Swap Used   23.7% (248,488 of 1,048,572)
```

With

```
ab -k -n 1000 -c 7 -l URL
```

I get:

```
Server Load 8.6 (4 CPUs)
```

Is this normal, or too high? I mean, I can get only **3 concurrent pageviews** with 4vCPU?

Answer (score 2):

Server load is not an absolute measurement. It depends on the Cores that are available on the system.

For example, in a 4 Core system, Load "4" is the same as Load "1" in a 1 Core system.

Since you have concurrency = 3 then, you might have 3 concurrent apache threads consuming the 3 out of your 4 Cores. That leads to a 3.something load which is OK.

Try to run ab with parameters of the simulated load you'd expect this server to handle. Like 10 concurrent, etc to check how the server will behave.

Also the type of the CPU cores plays an important role. I.e. is it a XEON CPU? V1 or V4? E3 or E5? etc

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
With concurrency = 7, server load goes to 8.60, which is too much high... I'm on a VPS. From WHM, I see total processor #4, QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+, Speed
1795.781 MHz, Cache 16384 KB

Comment: yes, 8.60 with 7 concurrent seems high. It needs more investigation to dig into to problem. It might be slow storage or something else.